# Unable to get element by ID within ngIf

Tags: angular, getelementbyid, angular-ng-if

I have been playing with A2 for a little while now and I understand that my problem is due to the sequence in which everything initialises and runs within A2 and due to the `*ngIf` in the html but what I don't understand is why or how to get my desired result.

Using the following test component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html' })

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    test: any;

    settest():void{ 
        //this.test = {test: 1}; --This works using ngAfterViewInit

        //This causes the console.log in ngAfterViewInit to be null
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.testService.getTest(params['id']))
            .subscribe(test => {
                this.test = test;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.settest();
        console.log(document.getElementById('test1')); --Null
        console.log(document.getElementById('test2')); -- Not NUll
    } 

    ngAfterViewInit(): void
    {
        console.log(document.getElementById('test1')); --Null
        console.log(document.getElementById('test2')); -- Not NUll
    } 
}
```

and `test.component.html`

```
<div *ngIf="test">
    <div id="test1"></div>
</div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

What I don't understand is why, even in the `ngOnInit` the `console.log` of `test1` returns `null` where as `test2` returns the element. I know it is because its within the `*ngIf`, but I don't understand why or what to do to access that element once its rendered so I can interact with it as part of the google maps API

**EDIT** Updated some code that I'd foolishly excluded.

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to a **`DOM element`** in **`ngAfterViewInit`** life cycle hook if you are using any **`angular context`** on that element. You can expect **`DOM element(with Angular context) to be fully available`** in **`ngAfterViewInit`** life cycle hook.

```
ngOnInit(): void
{
    this.settest();
    console.log(document.getElementById('test1'));   // not rendered
    console.log(document.getElementById('test2'));
} 


ngAfterViewInit(){
   console.log(document.getElementById('test1'));    // rendered
}
```

Comment: Still returns NULL, even in the `ngAfterViewInit`. Playing more with the code, as best I can tell its because of the async of the api call (which I'll update my answer with as I stupidly excluded it). If I remove the async call then `ngAfterViewInit()` works, if I keep `subscribe` then it doesn't.